# explode and implode in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Data

```
3   uploads/8/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png
3   uploads/10/thumbs/967693821370850253.png
3   uploads/9/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png
3   uploads/11/thumbs/967693821370850253.png
```

my input is id="20" now i need to change statically as  "uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png"  for every id 3.
i need output like this..

```
3   uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png
3   uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png
3   uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png
3   uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png
```

i have tried explode and implode but i can't change it how to do? i'll retrieve the  data  from database.

my coding is

```
function albums_download($input, $serviceName) {
    $ipJson = json_encode($input);
    $this->db->select('photo_thumb_url,photo_url');
    $this->db->from('photos');
    $this->db->where('album_id', $input['album_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
         $data[] = $row->photo_thumb_url;
         $data[] = $row->photo_url;

         $explode_data = explode('/',$row->photo_thumb_url);
         $explode_data[1] = 20;
         $data['change'] = implode('/', $explode_data);

    }

        $status = $this->privue_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);

    return $status;
```

}

Comment: you'll have to give more context for this question. you can tell explode what delimiter to use - explode('/',$filepath). You might also look at pathinfo() if you're trying to get the filenames and append them to another path.

Comment: What does the "3" on the left comes from ? Is it supposed to be an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say your data is $data array

try this

```
$data=array('uploads/8/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png',
      'uploads/10/thumbs/967693821370850253.png',
      'uploads/9/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png',
      'uploads/11/thumbs/967693821370850253.png');

foreach ($data as $row){
$temparray=explode('/',$row);
$temparray[1]=20;
echo implode('/',$temparray); 
}
```

Comment: function albums_download($input, $serviceName) {
$ipJson = json_encode($input);
$this->db->select('photo_thumb_url,photo_url');
$this->db->from('photos');
$this->db->where('album_id', $input['album_id']);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
$data[] = $row->photo_thumb_url;
$data[] = $row->photo_url;
$explode_data = explode('/',$row->photo_thumb_url);
$explode_data[1] = 20;
$data['change'] = implode('/', $explode_data);
}
$status = $this->privue_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
return $status;
}

Comment: as u said i have tried i got output like this                                                     <data>
      <_0>uploads/10/thumbs/4477334191370855280.png</_0>
      <_1>uploads/10/thumbs/19655101721370855799.png</_1>
      <_2>uploads/10/thumbs/3419363021370856463.png</_2>
      <change>uploads/20/thumbs/3419363021370856463.png</change>
   </data>

Answer (score 2):

I don't know CodeIgniter, but you can simply use a regex replace for this:

```
<?php
    $id = 20;

    $imagePaths = array(
        "uploads/8/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png",
        "uploads/10/thumbs/967693821370850253.png",
        "uploads/9/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png",
        "uploads/11/thumbs/967693821370850253.png"
    );

    foreach ($imagePaths as $imagePath) {
        $newImagePath = preg_replace("#^uploads/[0-9]+/#", "uploads/" . $id . "/", $imagePath);
        var_dump($newImagePath);
    }
?>
```

Would output:

> string(41) "uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png"
>   string(40) "uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png"
>   string(41) "uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png"
>   string(40) "uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png"

[**Live demo**](http://codepad.org/wByv6Gz3)

Explanation of regex:

- `^` - the string MUST start here
- `uploads/` - the literal string "uploads/"
- `[0-9]+` - the digits between 0 and 9 repeated one or more times
- `/` - the literal string "/"

We're replacing it with `uploads/{ID}/`.

Comment: This will change every entry, note the OP stated `for every id 3`.

Comment: as u said i have tried i got output like this <data> <_0>uploads/10/thumbs/4477334191370855280.png</_0> <_1>uploads/10/thumbs/19655101721370855799.png</_1> <_2>uploads/10/thumbs/3419363021370856463.png</_2> <change>uploads/20/thumbs/3419363021370856463.png</change> </data>

Answer (score 0):

try this, assuming that the paths are all the consistent.

```
$explode_data = explode('/', 'uploads/8/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png');
$explode_data[1] = 20;
$implode_data = implode('/', $explode_data);
```

this will return

```
uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regex

```
$images = array(
    "3 uploads/8/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png",
    "3 uploads/10/thumbs/967693821370850253.png",
    "3 uploads/9/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png",
    "4 uploads/9/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png",
    "3 uploads/11/thumbs/967693821370850253.png"
);

foreach ($images as &$im)
{
    if(substr($im, 0, 1) == '3')
    $im = preg_replace("#/[0-9]+/#",  "/20/", $im);
}
print_r($images);
```

**output:**

```
Array ( 
       [0] => 3 uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png 
       [1] => 3 uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png 
       [2] => 3 uploads/20/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png 
       [3] => 4 uploads/9/thumbs/8470177001370850253.png 
       [4] => 3 uploads/20/thumbs/967693821370850253.png
      )
```

`/[0-9]+/` looks for digits at least 1 time between / and / and replaces it with `/20/` foreach uses references so it can replace the value of variable in loop and then print it with print_r

**Edit:**

Changed to work only with strings that begins with 3

Comment: i can change only last value alone